# MySQL Query Particular customer with his transaction details

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i query a particular customer with all his transaction amount, currency and get the total amount of transaction the customer made in various currencies.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will return the SUM of amount per currency per customer.

```
SELECT customer_id,currency_code,SUM(amount) 
FROM your_table
--if you wants to see the result for a specific customer, add this following filter
WHERE customer_id = <put customer id here>
GROUP BY customer_id,currency_code
```

Comment: Simply totalling the amount column will give a rather meaningless answer since transactions can be in different currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to get currency wise total transactions of a particular customer.

For all customers:

```
SELECT customer_id,currency_code,SUM(amount) 
FROM transactions GROUP by customer_id, currency_code
```

For a particular customer:

```
SELECT customer_id,currency_code,SUM(amount) 
FROM transactions 
WHERE customer_id = <put it your customer_id> 
GROUP by customer_id, currency_code
```